# Firebase returning "undefined" value in React Native data fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch a list of Restaurants from the firebase realtime database,
my code snipped for that fetching the data -

```
_isMounted = false;

state :{
  data: [],
}

constructor(props){
  super(props)

  this.state = {
    data:[],
  }
}

componentDidMount(){
  this._isMounted = true
  this.getData()
}

componentWillUnmount(){
  this._isMounted = false
}

getData(){
  firebase.database().ref('Restaurants/').on("value", snapshot =>{
    let restaurantList = snapshot.val();
    console.log(restaurantList)
    this.setState({data: restaurantList})
  });
}
```

The data structure on Firebase is as follows - 
[image: Firebase data]

The console output for the array `restaurantList` is -

```
Array [
  undefined,
  Object {
    "location": "Testing data",
    "name": "Time Traveller",
    "rating": 4.5,
    "tags": "Indian, Asian",
  },
  Object {
    "locations": "Testing data",
    "name": "Novelty",
    "rating": 4.5,
    "tags": "Indian",
  },
]
```

I am not sure from where I am getting the `undefined` item in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
getData(){
  firebase.database().ref('Restaurants/').on("value", snapshot =>{
  snapshot.forEach((childSub) => {
    let key = childSub.key;
    let restaurantList = childSub.val();
    console.log(restaurantList);
   });
  });
}
```

The undefined is the key, try iterating inside the keys and retrieving the data